# Html5 mode with Hashbang Route for direct url on pages

Tags: angularjs, html, apache, url, seo

I'm using AngularJS for my Portfolio. I would like to make it compatible and crawled entirely by Googlebot. So, I tried to set the html5 mode in the config.

The '#' is now gone but I can't access to pages directly. Server send me a 404.

I'm using an Apache server. I normally configure my server to route request on index with the .htaccess.

My portfolio is already on a server [My portfolio](http://www.antoinecaron.ovh)

You can see the code on my github [Here](https://github.com/Slashgear/portfolio)

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure your server so that it redirect all routing requests to angular...

[read here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)
**How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode**

in apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```